# Angular Mat-Table Export CSV/Excel Does Not Export All Data In Complex Column

Tags: angular, mat-table, mat-table-exporter

I am using Angular 9 and Material 10. I have a few Mat-Table(s), they display and export to Excel/CSV using MatTableExporter as per all good examples. However I have an issue if the column is in a complex way.

I have a column that requires a currency symbol and an amount. I have obtained the symbol with an Enum and displays perfectly however when exported only the currency is exported not the amount. Where a currency symbol is Null the amount exports.

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="remainingAmount">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
    Outstanding Amount
  </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
    {{ currencySymbol[element.currencyCode] }} {{ element.remainingAmount }}
  </td>
</ng-container>
```

Displays  (USD) 100   if currency symbol exists or just displays 100
Excel/CSV  Prints (USD) if currency exists else 100 in the relevant column.

I would like (USD) 100 to print into the Excel/CSV column.

Comment: try " {{ currencySymbol[element.currencyCode] }} {{ element.remainingAmount }} " this

Comment: @PushpikaWan - that does give the data in both excel and csv however I'm left with the quotation marks in both the display and the excel column. I tried with single quote also worked but with same side effect. taking your "enclosing" of the statements further I wrapped them in a span, no other characters in display or Excel column. However prints as before in the CSV column. Very strange.

Comment: It does work with CSV but inserts line break into it

Comment: then you can remove line breaks right?